# Java to Kotlin_ Gson.Json Conversion Error

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

While converting from java to kotlin the output is given as follows
 Java:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    String strObj = getIntent().getStringExtra("passdata");
    userDictionery  = gson.fromJson(strObj, Map.class);
```

Kotlin:

```
val gson = Gson()
    val strObj = intent.getStringExtra("passdata")
    userDictionery = gson.fromJson<Map<*, *>>(strObj, Map<*, *>::class.java) as Map<String, String>?
```

But second line in kotlin shows an error that - **Only Classes are allowed left hand side of the class literal**

variable **userDictionery** is declared as `Map<String, String>`

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference classes with their generic parameters in Kotlin the same way you can't reference them in java. So `Map<*, *>::class` is in the same way invalid in Kotlin as `Map<?, ?>.class` is in Java. Replace this:

```
gson.fromJson<Map<*, *>>(strObj, Map<*, *>::class.java)
```

With that:

```
gson.fromJson<Map<*, *>>(strObj, Map::class.java)
```

Comment: thanks for support. I've updated code with non null check also